# Align camera rotation with grid/ticks in SceneView

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a globe positioned at SCNVector3.zero with orbitTurntable/allowsCameraControl and a camera using SCNLookAtConstraint to look at the globe. This is working very well. What I'd like to add is the ability to clean up the rotations so that free rotations are snapped to nearest 5degrees and it makes a click sound every time it passes 5degree tick mark. What's the best way to approach this?

I haven't had any luck.. inside of renderer() I have tried SCNTransformConstraint, SCNMatrix4MakeRotation, SCNAction.rotateBy, and of course just changing eulerAngles.x/y directly. Any guidance appreciated! Thank you!!

```
var scnView: SCNView = {
  let v = SCNView()
  v.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
  v.allowsCameraControl = true
  v.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .orbitTurntable
  v.defaultCameraController.target = SCNVector3.zero
  v.defaultCameraController.inertiaEnabled = true
  return v
}()
let camConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: scene?.rootNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some success turning the camera control off

```
    v.allowsCameraControl = false
```

Then using the pan gesture

```
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panHandler(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

But ultimately I used this from https://github.com/dclelland/DirectedPanGestureRecognizer

```
    let gestureRecognizer = DirectedPanGestureRecognizer()
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

I had to write my own code for rotations etc but it was worth it!